# Is it possible to get state information about the terminal window / tab a bash script is running in?

Tags: bash

Apologies in advance if this has already been asked - it's really hard to search for this as bash and terminal show up together in so many places.

Basically what I'd like to be able to do is have a bash script be aware of whether or not the terminal it's running in is currently active (selected) so that I could use notify-send to inform the user something has completed only if it's not currently the active window. I'm guessing it would be possible to do something that can at least detect whether the active window is a terminal window by accessing gnome somehow, but I have no idea how and I imagine it would likely be a hack, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging I've found a workable solution so I'm going to post it as an answer, but it's not very portable so I'd still appreciate any better solutions.

What I've found is that when using Gnome you have access to a $WINDOWID variable from the gnome-terminal (this doesn't work if you've ssh'ed to another box unfortunately and so isn't ideal). This can be combined with xprop like this:

```
activeWindow=$(xprop -root | awk '/_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW\(WINDOW\)/{print $NF}')
thisWindow=$(printf '0x%x\n' $WINDOWID)
```

Which can then be compared for equality. A more suitable way of getting the current window id would be good however.

Edit: Having seen Zaytzev's answer I guess this could be combined so instead of using $WINDOWID I could set the terminal title and check whether `xprop -id $activeWindow WM_NAME` is equal to my window title.

Answer (score 1):

Well this question is rather about xserver and window management then bash itself. You need 2 things for this:

- package with xprop, this is xutils if I remember correctly.
- you need to set unique terminal window name, so you could later find it on window stack, here is working example: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/set-terminal-title-dynamically-803469/

a) to find your window:

```
$> xprop -root _NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING
```

It gives an output like:

```
_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING(WINDOW): window id # 0xe0001e, 0x3a0006d, 0x1a00004
```

This is window stack so the last window is on top. You need to extract list of window ids (0xe0001e 0x3a0006d 0x1a00004).

Next you have to iterate over that list of ids. You will find your window by examining this property:

```
 xprop -id <win id> WM_NAME
```

b) Example how to raise your window is here:
[X11: raise an existing window via command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028972/x11-raise-an-existing-window-via-command-line)

Comment: This is quite interesting, but unfortunately on my system at least _NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING doesn't return the desired result. Getting the WM_NAME of the ids returned gives me something that looks right, but then has 4 additional entries ("bin", "Docky", "Top Expanded Edge Panel", and "Bottom Expanded Edge Panel").

Comment: xwinfo shows the title as well, you can extract it from there. `xwininfo -id <win id> | grep "Window\ id" | cut -d\" -f2`